# google-drive-ruby, Pull Worksheet to populate Scaffold

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to

- 1.) Connect to Google Drive
- 2.) Locate a specific Worksheet
- **3.) Pull that worksheet into my DB**

I'm working with [google-drive-ruby gem](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby), [Google Drive API Documentation (Ruby)](http://gimite.net/doc/google-drive-ruby/GoogleDrive/Spreadsheet.html)

---

1.) `session = GoogleDrive.login("username@gmail.com", "mypassword")`

2.) `ws = session.spreadsheet_by_key("key").worksheet_by_title('Data')`

Up to this point i have access to `Worksheet: Data`.

---

**3.) I'm stuck here.** I'm trying to pull the Data and populate my DB with it.

The Spreadsheet has `5 Columns` and `Headers`.

From the gem's Documentation:

```
# Dumps all cells.
for row in 1..ws.num_rows
  for col in 1..ws.num_cols
    p ws[row, col]
  end
end
```

That is as closest as I come to the Data in that Worksheet :)..

How can I take that data an pull it into my DB (e.g. Contact.create(data from the Worksheet).

Most importantly I didn't fully understand how I can assign a specific column to a given attribute of my Model.

E.g.

```
Column 1 => :name
Column 2 => :email
etc...
```

A little help would be much appreciated, Cheers.

Comment: How is the `Contact` class initialized?

Comment: It's a simple scaffold.

Comment: can you copy the class?  what attributes does it need to be initialized?

Comment: Could you join me in chat for a minute => http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56652/google-drive-ruby

Comment: Regards "Column 1 => :name ...": Don't think you want them, they look like "list feed", but looks like your example is "cell feed". I gave up with list feed, as Cell feed has more control.